# Vega lite Top N stacked bars Transform

Tags: json, visualization, vega-lite

How can I display the Top N of stacked bars using Vega lite and transform?

It works fine when working with single bars but I am struggling when the bars are stacked.

Example for single bars:

```
"transform": [

{"aggregate": [{"op": "sum","field": "INVOICE_TOTAL", "as": "INVTOT"}],"groupby": ["CITY"]},

{"sort": [{"field": "INVTOT", "order": "descending"}],"window": [{"op": "row_number", "as": "rank"}]},

{"filter": "datum.rank <= 20"},

],
```

I have setup a sample page here:
https://apbreports.com/dashboards/vega_lite_2023-03-15/html/TOPN.html

As you can see the first chart is ok but need help with the second chart.

Thanks again.

I have tried several transforms without luck. Maybe a lookup is the answer.

Comment: Can you supply a minimal reproducible example in the online vega editor? Thanks

Comment: Hi David, we could use this example: https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/window.html#top-k if we add a calculate column and combine 3 letters in each group (ABC, DEF, GHI etc) then show top K on this new calculated column and make the bars stack on student column.

Comment: We could use this as a good starting point. https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/examples/stacked_bar_h.html Then we need to show just the 3 largest bars based on variety. Correct result would be 3 stacks : Wisconsin, Trebi, No 457.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

To do a top n, first do a joinaggregate transform, then a window transform with a dense rank and finally a filter transform.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {"url": "data/barley.json"},
  "transform": [
    {
      "joinaggregate": [{"op": "sum", "field": "yield", "as": "total"}],
      "groupby": ["variety"]
    },
    {
      "window": [{"op": "dense_rank", "as": "rank"}],
      "sort": [{"field": "total", "order": "descending"}]
    },
    {"filter": "datum.rank <= 3"}
  ],
  "mark": "bar",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"aggregate": "sum", "field": "yield"},
    "y": {"field": "variety"},
    "color": {"field": "site"}
  }
}
```